# Render JSX-element conditionally based on whether source object has deeply nested properties with certain values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to hide a button if there is atleast one order or subareas that at least one orders whose status `'ACCEPTED'` or `'DONE'`.

How can I hide the "Hide me" Menu item when either item has at least one area with order status `'ACCEPTED'` OR `'DONE'` or at least one area with subareas order with `status` `'ACCEPTED'` or `'DONE'`.

Below is the react code with the item I am trying to process

```
function Parent() {
    const item = {
        owner: {
            id: '1',
            cognitoId: '2',
        },
        areas: [{
                id: '1',
                orders: [{
                        id: '1',
                        status: 'ASSIGNED',
                    }, {
                        id: '2',
                        status: 'ACCEPTED',
                    }
                ],
                subAreas: [{
                        id: '1',
                        orders: [{
                                id: '4',
                                status: 'DONE',
                            }
                        ],
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                id: '2',
                orders: [{
                        id: '3',
                        status: 'ASSIGNED',
                    }, {
                        id: '4',
                        status: 'ACCEPTED',
                    }
                ],
                subAreas: [{
                        id: '2',
                        orders: [{
                                id: '5',
                                status: 'DONE',
                            }, {
                                id: '6',
                                status: 'ACCEPTED',
                            }
                        ],
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    return ({
        item && item.owner && item.owner.cognitoId && (
             < Menu > Hide me <  / Menu > )
    });
}
```

EDIT

**strong text**

As per the solution provided i have tried like below,

```
const hasDoneAccepted = () => {
    Object
        .keys(item)
            .some(key =>
                (key === 'status' &&
                    ['DONE', 'ACCEPTED'].includes(item[key])) || //error                  //here
                    (typeof item[key] == 'object' && //error here
                    hasDoneAccepted(item[key])) //error here
};
```

But this gives me error

Element implicitly has any type because expression of type "status" cant be used on index type 'Item'. property status doesnt exist on type 'Item'.

EDIT2**strong text**

based on solution for typescript implemented like below,

```
const hasDoneAccepted = (o: any) => {
    const output = Object.keys(o).some(
        key =>
            (key === 'status' && ['DONE', 'ACCEPTED'].indexOf(o[key]) > -1)  ||
            (typeof o[key] === 'object' && hasDoneAccepted(o[key]))
    );
    return output;
};

console.log("output***", hasDoneAccepted(item));
```

this doesnt give any errors but in runtime the app breaks. and in the console i see the error.

"cannnot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: Your object is invalid. You are missing commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may traverse recursively (e.g. with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)) your source object all deep through to find out, whether some key, named `status` has value either`'DONE'` or `'ACCEPTED'` within nested properties:

```js
const item = {owner:{id:'1',cognitoId:'2',},areas:[{id:'1',orders:[{id:'1',status:'ASSIGNED',},{id:'2',status:'ACCEPTED',}],subAreas:[{id:'1',orders:[{id:'4',status:'DONE',}],}]},{id:'2',orders:[{id:'3',status:'ASSIGNED',},{id:'4',status:'ACCEPTED',}],subAreas:[{id:'2',orders:[{id:'5',status:'DONE',},{id:'6',status:'ACCEPTED',}],}]}]},

      hasDoneAccepted = o =>
        Object
          .keys(o)
          .some(key => 
            (key == 'status' &&
            ['DONE', 'ACCEPTED'].includes(o[key])) ||
            (typeof o[key] == 'object' &&
            hasDoneAccepted(o[key])))
            
console.log(hasDoneAccepted(item))
```

So, your conditional rendering may look something, like that:

```
function Parent() {
   const hasDoneAccepted = ..
   ..
   return !!item?.owner?.cognitoId && hasDoneAccepted(item) && 
          (<Menu>Hide me</Menu>)
}
```

Comment: thanks but somehow it is not working for me. i have added what i have tried to my question. and the error i am getting.

Comment: @saritha : you're getting errors *mostly* because of the way you deployed my code. Check out [working typescript snippet over here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rwe9zx)

Comment: i dint understand what the solution could be.

Comment: @saritha : [typescript snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rwe9zx) seems to work perfectly fine. Is there a problem deploying that as-is in your own component (errors, warnings, etc)?

Comment: yes i see error in console "cannot convert undefined or null to object" i have updated my question with what i have tried. thanks.

Comment: @saritha : I suspect, you didn't refactor `return` statement (as it seems to have certain issues) similarly to my snippet. If you may post your own live snippet, reproducing the problem, it would be much easier to support you to debug your code.

Comment: i shall accept this answer and create other question with the problem. thanks.

Comment: was just debugging this. logging Object.keys(items) doesnt give me status as output.

Comment: @saritha : `Object.keys()` is supposed to output an array of keynames (of `items` in your example), since there's no `status` key among top level properties it doesn't return that. My code does check whether there're nested objects and checks *their* properties as well looking for `status`. If no `status: 'DONE'` or `status: 'ACCEPTED'` but more nested objects it iterates through those as well until it finds necessary values or reaches the bottom of this hierarchy.

Comment: hmm true. but somehow using the code you provided gives errors in my code editor. i have no clue whats going in there

Comment: @saritha : as I said, use [codesandbox](https://codesanbox.io) or [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) to post a sample of your code throwing those errors, and I may help you to debug that, ad-hoc troubleshooting won't work